# How To Backup System To External Source And Then Use Boot From It?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, bootable-media, windows-backup, syncback

I know *Windows 7 has built-in backup facility* and i also am familiar with *2BrightSparks' SyncBackSE utility*.

I have questions about backing up **sensitive information to external source** and **booting from it in case of emergency**:

1. If i backup with Windows 7 built-in
   backup facility, will i be able to
   later use external source as boot
   device? If yes, must i choose
   recommended backup or customized
   backup?
2. If i backup with SyncBackSE, will i
   be able to boot from external
   source?

Would you **recommend/rely on** Windows 7 built-in backup facility?
What other backup utilities would you recommend for backing up sensitive data and booting from external source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not reccomend Windows Backup after the fun and ga,es I've seen with it in the apst.
I would throughly recommend [Acronis True Image with Universal Restore](http://www.acronis.co.uk/promo/Choose-Universal-Restore/index.html?source=uk_googleAUR&ad=aur&c=11026635712&k=acronis%20true%20image%20universal%20restore&gclid=CO6X7qzoh6kCFYFB4QodFGL9iQ). It's not free but the software is fantastic. I've restored everything from Laptops to Servers onto dis-similar hardware and never had a problem.
You can even choose to include a drivers disk at startup so you can take the driver executables and strip them down to their component files using a tool such as [UniExtract](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) and specify these files to be loaded at restore.
Once the restore is finished you have a fully functioning computer with the correct dirvers installed.

One final point, whenever creating a backup and restore stratergy make sure you;re continually testing and checking that both parts work. The backup and the **restore**. Too often people concentrate on the backup only and run into problems when they try and restore their data.

Comment: Joe how do i restore system image from external source onto my computer's hard drive after formatting hard drive? Does image come with bootable utility that allows me to (format, fdisk and other MS-DOS tools) restore backup to a hard drive?

Comment: Acronis comes with the option to create bootable media running from its own Linux based kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in windows 7 backup programs. But if you want to be absolutely sure you can boot from it you can make a mirror of your disk.
You could use for example use "hirens boot cd" or other software for mirroring hard drives.